# Map. jQuery plugin to create a mini analog google-maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps

There is a great image - map. On a map specific locations (each location has its own icon). Clicking on the icon to display a summary of this place.

Can you advise what to use for this plugin, or maybe there is a ready-made tools.
Or is it better not to reinvent the wheel (although so interesting:) and use google maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Ground overlays](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#GroundOverlays) or [Custom overlays](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#CustomOverlays) from [Google maps API v3](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html) - there is a very good documentation with examples ([ground overlay](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple.html), [custom overlay](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple.html)).

Ground overlays seems to be simpler, you just put an image over the map and specify corner coordinates. Custom overlays allow for more functionality, but are more complex to use.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Google Maps API v3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html), which does everything you seem to be asking for.